# Oracle insert into using select to add first row and return columns without using pl/sql stored procedure

Tags: oracle

I have requirement to insert single row using select statement and return the values inserted into table. Application needs to hold value of inserted values to use further in application. I need to use insert with returning option since select uses max hence select will always return single column and additionally i can add condition to return single row from select statement.
I need to avoid use of plsql and has to be done in single statement.

```
    INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE (COLID)
      SELECT max( COLID ) +1  FROM APPLICATIONTABLE
      WHERE  ROWNUM <=1 RETURNING colid;
```

i get error SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, I dont wish to use declare statement using variable.

Comment: Not possible: (a) you can't use `returning` clause with insert...select only with insert...values; (b) you would have to declare a variable to return the value into - `returning columnid into var`.

Comment: Thanks @TonyAndrews, does Declare col Begin insertstatmenet with select  returning cols into col end , is it going to solve the problem I could not understand your comment (a)

Comment: I'll try an answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. You must return the value into something - a variable or a parameter
2. You cannot use `returning` with an insert statement based on a select statement.

This would work:

```
DECLARE
 v1 APPLICATIONTABLE.colid%type;
 v2 TEMPTABLE.columnid%type;
BEGIN
 SELECT max( COLID ) +1  
   INTO v1
   FROM APPLICATIONTABLE;
 INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE (COLID) VALUES (v1)
      RETURNING columnid INTO v2;
END;
```

Or if (as I guess) you meant `columnid` to be `colid` then:

```
DECLARE
 v1 APPLICATIONTABLE.colid%type;
BEGIN
 SELECT max( COLID ) +1  
   INTO v1
   FROM APPLICATIONTABLE;
 INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE (COLID) VALUES (v1);
END;
```

By the way, `max( COLID ) + 1` raises a warning flag to me: it is generally preferable to use a [sequence](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314) instead of this method for generating new keys:

```
DECLARE
 v1 APPLICATIONTABLE.colid%type;
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO TEMPTABLE (COLID) VALUES (colidseq.nextval) 
    RETURNING colid INTO v1;
END;
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, I meant 'colid' sorry i had mistype. Is it going to be atomic operation if I use java to execute this I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know Java!